# What email program does iWatch use by default?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring

I'm trying to see what email program iWatch uses by default for sending out alerts after I define the contact email addresses for specific alerts. I don't see the mail program defined among any of the configuration files, yet I see some iWatch documentation discussing its raw use in config files which somewhat defeats the point of having contact email addresses if iWatch also doesn't define which email program to use. I can provide any of my config files as references if need-be.

Comment: You mean “Apple Watch?” if so, it’s the built in watchOS app and mailer.

Comment: iWatch !=  Watch

Comment: facepalm. I figured it out. the answer is sendmail.

Comment: Why did you tag this as Linux and Ubuntu? This is an Apple question...there's even an entire Apple stackexchange to ask there too

Comment: @Tetsujin Can you provide a link for context as to what this question is about then?

Comment: http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html Nothing whatsoever to do with Apple... ever wondered why they didn't call the  Watch an iWatch?

Comment: @QuickishFM This is the link to the Ubuntu iWatch program, dipstick: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/iwatch.1.html now kindly remove your downvote

Comment: Yes, I will do. I assumed it was something to do with Apple Watch - my apologies.

Answer (score -2):

The answer to this question is Sendmail

Comment: Not really. Unclearly presented questions are one knock that could have been avoided, though your's was matched by an unfortunate comparison to a popular mobile device whose questions are off topic here. There are many ways the question could have been presented more clearly, and the answer, frankly, raises more questions that it answers.